# URL validation must contain http or https

Tags: php, regex

I am searching multiple websites to fix this issue. The problem is I am asking user to enter website address and like people says never trust user input.

So, possible scenario can be like this:

> https or http://www.google.com
>
> https or http://google.com
>
> www.google.com
>
> google.com

Now I want URL must be like this. http or https//www.google.com

At the moment I have below code but it is not working as expected.

```
$url = "www.google.com";    
if (preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $url)) {
      echo "URL is valid";
    }
    else {
      echo "URL is invalid";
    }
```

Comment: use `parse_url`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: if you can explain why then it would be great. Thanks for downvoting

Comment: Alternatively perhaps use `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`

Comment: I picked a bad dupe.

Comment: it happens @AbraCadaver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the start of the string contains `http` which also includes `https` AND check if it's a valid URL:

```
if((strpos($url, 'http') === 0) && filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo "URL is valid";
} else {
    echo "URL is invalid";
}
```

Comment: Your solution is correct. I was stupid to checking regex. Its so easy. Thanks Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Expression

```
/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi
```

It will aceept all the cases that you have mentioned above

Comment: i want only one condition to be correct (http://www.google.com) rest should be invalid.